# Header reappear on scroll up not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, css

My company wanted our website header to disappear on scroll down but reappear on scroll up, which I was able to do with JS and CSS - it works fine on Desktop but doesn't work on mobile. I am using Wordpress and Beaver Builder (I have escalated to Beaver Builder in case something might be blocking it?)

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
document.getElementById("header-global").style.top = "0";
} else {
document.getElementById("header-global").style.top = "-100px";
}
prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
```

And the following CSS:

```
#header-global {
position:fixed;
Width: 100%;
transition: 0.3s;
z-index: 20;
}
```

The function works perfectly fine on desktop but I not on mobile. I have the Beaver Builder header plugin, which I have confirmed sticky header is not activated. Is there anything else blocking it for mobile / am I doing something wrong? Note that my JS knowledge is limited..

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: put a complete example of code in a snippet and make sure it works properly to show the issue.

Comment: That is the all of the code that I inserted. Am I missing anything?

Comment: where is HTML??

Comment: This is created with Beaver Builder theme - so front end drag and drop and for custom modules, changes you add CSS, JS or HTML - this is for the specific feature. I can copy paste the entire page's HTML if you need?

Answer (score 0):

Needed to decrease the px as shown below

```
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
    var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("header-global").style.top = "0";
    } else {
    document.getElementById("header-global").style.top = "-200px";
    }
    prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
```